# Why does this npm error appear when installing dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm

i am trying to install project dependencies using npm but i am currently getting this in return

```
    npm ERR! code ENETUNREACH
    npm ERR! errno ENETUNREACH
    npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib/-/tslib-2.0.0.tgz failed, reason: connect ENETUNREACH 104.16.23.35:443
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in your terminal to revert back to the default regsitry.

```
npm config set proxy null
npm config set https-proxy null
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: still outputs the same :<

Comment: what is your node and npm version ?

Comment: currently at v12.20.0, cus the work repo that i cloned has its dependencies installed using this version. though i tried running sudo npm i with the LTS version, it still outputs the same

Comment: Try this might this work.
This isn't recommended, however, since your packages will then be downloaded insecurely. It would be best to find the actual root cause instead of using a work-around like this.

`npm config set strict-ssl false`

Comment: oh okay, may i know what does it do? and why it isn't recommended? :) thanks!

Comment: your packages will  be downloaded insecurely. that's why you should not use.